# Q-in-Q on QFX5120

Tags: juniper, switching, qinq, dot1q

I'm building dot1Q tunneling between 2 Cisco routers and when I used only 1 QFX switch it all works fine.
However when I try to use 2 QFX switches with basically the same configuration I cannot get this done. The problem is between the 2 QFX devices where the double tagged packets should traverse.
All documentations I've read suggest the config that is used below, but it's not working. I tried different approached without success.

Do you have any idea what might be the problem?
(20.2R1.10)

**CE1** e0/0-------xe-0/0/0 **QFX1** xe-0/0/1-------xe-0/0/1 **QFX2** xe-0/0/0------e0/0 **CE2**

## CE1

```
interface Ethernet0/0
 no ip address
!
interface Ethernet0/0.100
 encapsulation dot1Q 100
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Ethernet0/0.200
 encapsulation dot1Q 200
 ip address 20.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Ethernet0/0.300
 encapsulation dot1Q 300
 ip address 30.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
```

## QFX1

```
interfaces {
    xe-0/0/0 {
        flexible-vlan-tagging;
        mtu 1522;
        encapsulation extended-vlan-bridge;
        unit 999 {
            vlan-id-list 100-800;
            input-vlan-map push;
            output-vlan-map pop;
        }
    }
    # This one seems to be wrong
    xe-0/0/1 {
        flexible-vlan-tagging;
        encapsulation extended-vlan-bridge;
        unit 999 {
            vlan-id 999;
        }
    }

vlans {
    v999 {
        interface xe-0/0/0.999;
        interface xe-0/0/1.999;
    }
}
```

## QFX2

```
interfaces {
    xe-0/0/0 {
        flexible-vlan-tagging;
        mtu 1522;
        encapsulation extended-vlan-bridge;
        unit 999 {
            vlan-id-list 100-800;
            input-vlan-map push;
            output-vlan-map pop;
        }
    }
    xe-0/0/1 {
        flexible-vlan-tagging;
        encapsulation extended-vlan-bridge;
        unit 999 {
            vlan-id 999;
        }
    }

vlans {
    v999 {
        interface xe-0/0/0.999;
        interface xe-0/0/1.999;
    }
}
```

## CE2

```
interface Ethernet0/0
 no ip address
!
interface Ethernet0/0.100
 encapsulation dot1Q 100
 ip address 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.0
!
interface Ethernet0/0.200
 encapsulation dot1Q 200
 ip address 20.0.0.2 255.255.255.0
!
interface Ethernet0/0.300
 encapsulation dot1Q 300
 ip address 30.0.0.2 255.255.255.0
```